# Monodevelop: Debug a process that I didn't launch myself

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, monodevelop, xbuild

I'm writing a `.dll` using Monodevelop on Linux that is run by an application, and I have no control over how or when my code is called, but I would like to debug that DLL.

How can I make Monodevelop's debugger attach to that DLL when a chosen method is run in the DLL ?

Alternatively, I thought about starting the debugger from the code itself (i.e. "from now on, please debug me").

The DLL I'm writing contains a `xbuild` task that throws and obscure exception when run using xbuild (but the code runs fine if I call it from `main`), so if there's any way to debug custom xbuild tasks, I'm interested in that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your library project options
- On left side go to Build->Output
- Output path: set to path where external application will load your dll
- On left side go to Run->Custom Commands
- In dropdown box with text (Select a project operation) change to "Execute"
- In Command textbox set to external executable that loads your dll

Now you can right click on your library project in SoltuionPad and set "Set As Startup Project"